# How It is with sharing content on Facebook

Tags: copyright, internet, intellectual-property, terms-of-service

Facebook Terms of Service contains (3.8.2015) the following text in section 2.4:

> When you publish content or information using the Public setting, it means that you are allowing everyone, including people off of Facebook, to access and use that information, and to associate it with you (i.e., your name and profile picture).

Does this mean everyone is allowed to use that content (republish, remix...), when you publish it using **Public** setting?

What happens If user who originally published published content, removes it?

Comment: Why do you think it means anything other than exactly what it says?

Comment: @Dale M I've googled and found many sites saying that using this type of content is illegal. That's why I'm not sure.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No. That clause does not give other users a licence to reproduce the work (other than what is necessary to access or use it) or create derivative works. The copyright owner has the exclusive right to do those things. (See [17 USC 106](https://www.law.cornell.edu/uscode/text/17/106).)

The clause you quote only indicates that other users can "access" (download for viewing) your "information" and use it, too. It doesn't give away any of your exclusive copyright in the work.

You *do* grant *Facebook* a licence to do certain things with your work in section 2.1 of the Terms of Service, though.